# Ubuntu - установка программ, объясните новичку, пожалуйста

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всех приветствую.
Недавно перешел, а если точнее, пытаюсь перейти на Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), поэтому, как и все после Windows, слегка в шоке от процесса установки программ.
Если по существу, то пытаюсь установить **ptpython** или **ipython**. Следую указаниям, поставил PIP, через него поставил ptpython или ipython, вроде как все пакеты скачались, ошибок не выдало, но через терминал ptpython не запускается:

```
genrikh@77529:/$ ptpython

Command 'ptpython' not found, did you mean:

  command 'pvpython' from deb paraview-python
  command 'pmpython' from deb pcp

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

С ipython та же беда. Просто в приложения их нигде нет.
Вопрос банален, но все же - как ставить приложения, чтоб они запускались и если не запускаются, то где и как выискивать весь лишний мусор, который скачался и не работает?

```
genrikh@77529:~$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/genrikh/.local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/home/genrikh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/home/genrikh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/home/genrikh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 20, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application, create_eventloop, create_prompt_layout, create_output
ImportError: cannot import name create_prompt_application
```

Comment: ptpython это модуль для python, а не самостоятельная программа.

Comment: возможно. в макулутаре, по которой я учу Питон, просто сказано - альтернатива командной строке Python.

Comment: пакет [ipython](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ipython) имеется в официальном репозитории. так что `$ sudo apt install ipython`

Comment: именно так я его и ставил. как теперь его запустить?

Comment: Вы не поверите — *ipython*.

Comment: Скорее всего, установленную через сторонний пакетный менеджер программу не видно глобально, потому что вы её без sudo установили.

Answer (score 2):

Ipython и Ptpython -это оболочки,в которых ведется работа. Иными словами, это работа с все той же консолью, но имеющей свои особенности.Загрузка и установка происходит через pip или pip3 , которые не требуют прав рута
`pip3 install ipython` или `pip3 install ptpython`

Вызов происходит обычным вызовом команд из консоли - **ipython** или - **ptpython**.Устанавливать желательно в домашнюю папку, возможно вы криво притянули, удалите и попробуйте еще раз установить

> Заметьте, что для не для debian-based может потребоваться ключ --user

А вообще ,конечно, желательно использовать Jupyter.

Comment: `pip3 install --user` тогда уж, иначе они ругнутся на ошибку доступа (как минимум у меня ругаются)

Comment: Ну и обычный вызов команд из консоли при этом не сработает, потому что исполняемых файлов  /usr/bin или /usr/local/bin не появится и консоль заявит, что команда не найдена

Comment: Все возможно, это ведь линукс)

Comment: Я вот у себя проверил сейчас (выполнил свои инструкции) и у меня все работает

Comment: Не поделитесь скриншотом? Я вам не верю, у меня ошибка доступа https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGGgk.png

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/89f73b19ee4b1c2ac7e2c987b76c8c13

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88258/discussion-between-mickeyu-and-andreymal).